# Multiple clients using Netty

Tags: java, concurrency, tcp, netty

Iam starting with Netty and I've tried the [echo example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/echo)

I would like to simulate lots of clients connected to a server instead of just one like on the example.

I can see on the EchoClient code that the client is initiated by

```
new EchoClient(host, port, firstMessageSize).run();
```

As a very first attempt I tried to put that inside a for loop that iterates 1000 times

```
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        new EchoClient(host, port, firstMessageSize).run();
}
```

But this isn't working.

How can I do in order to create many client connections?

I would like to simulate many connections to an already done tcp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should share the ClientSocketChannelFactory between your different clients. The rest should be the same as in the example. If you not share you will create too many threads.